# How can I invert photo colors on iOS?

Tags: photos, ios

I'm looking for a way to invert individual photo colors in iOS 7 to use as a background instead of inverting the entire phones color scheme. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

You can download the app [Photoshop express (free)](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/adobe-photoshop-express/id331975235) that has this feature.

Comment: Please include brief instructions for finding this in the app, currently that application doesn't seem to include the requested functionality.

Comment: As of today Photoshop Express for iOS does **not** support inverting an image.